# Display of a window with scrolling of an entrance of Facebook after pressing of the "Like" button

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-likebox

I have posted on the website the Like button from Facebook. I am using Facebook’s JavaScript SDK in an application. If the user isn't logged into FB, I get the following window with horizontal and vertical scrollbars:

[image]

Confuses only this window with scrollings. And if I add instead of URL on my group, other URL (for example on the website of Facebook), then the entrance window without scrollings is displayed

[image]

Attach the JS SDK code which I add

```
<script> window.fbAsyncInit =
                 function () {
                     FB.init({ appId: "1111111111111111", xfbml: true, version: "v2.12" }), FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
                 },

                    (function(d, s, id) {
               var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
               if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
               js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
               js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12';
               fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
         }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>
```

And code of the button

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/my-group-name" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
```

All this is done by me locally in the development mode. How it is possible to make that the window is opened without scrollbars or opened in a new tab?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: "1111111111111111",
        xfbml: true,
        version: "v2.12"
    }), FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
}, (function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```